# O_APPEND flag on one file makes read() system call behave weirdly on other files

Tags: c, file-io, posix

I have a C program which creates a specified number of files (name- myfiles) in a directory. Then removes all the files. Then creates a very large file (name -appfile), appends it, truncates it.
Several rounds of above operations are performed in a loop.

In order to verify each `write`, I read destination file from the same offset, where it had written the data. This verification part(read()) goes very well if test does not use O_APPEND flag for large file. But Otherwise, read starts showing weird behavior. After completion of 1st round of the test, either bytes read by read is 0 or lesser than the buffer size Or if the number of bytes are equal to buffer size than the content of both buffers mismatch.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you posted your actual code. What you wrote would be good to put in code comments.

Comment: Don't describe your code, but show it. Read this: [mcve]. BTW are you sure you really need `pread` instead of `read` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `destflg=O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT;`, I assume two things:

1. You're opening the file in append mode
2. You're running on Linux.

`pwrite()` on Linux is broken.

From [the Linux `pwrite()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html):

> **BUGS**
>
> POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should have
>   no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data.  However, on
>          Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()` appends data to
>          the end of the file, regardless of the value of `offset`.

Comment: O_APPEND flag has only been used for the large file(named apfill). And the verification part fails for all the other source file size files which were created initially by mytest()

Comment: @NhG11 Well, if you're running on Linux and using `pwrite()` on a file opened with `O_APPEND`, the data gets appended to the file.  Is that what's happening?

Comment: I realized that In first iteration of loop, At the time of creation of largefile, it modifies destflg variable with O_APPEND and misses to change it back to previous value for other iterations. So all other files(which are going to be created as sparse files) also get opened in O_APPEND mode and that is why reading offset beyond EOF results in 0 bytes or sometimes data gets read at wrong offset and then mismatch.